# jQuery script not working as excepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, this, window.location

I have a `jQuery` script that *should* open images full size when they are clicked.

```
$('img').click( function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    window.location.href=src;
});
```

However, when images are clicked they don't open as expected. Does anyone have any idea why? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: You need a dom ready handler, and also make sure jquery is loaded before calling this snippet

Comment: `$(this).attr('src');` returns relative path, use instead: `var src = this.src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n6n5R/

So, there is likely some issue with your event handler getting installed properly.  Here are things to check:

1. Are you waiting for the `document` to load before installing your event handlers?
2. Are your images dynamically loaded?
3. Do you have any script errors that are preventing your event handler from running?

For item #1, I would suggest this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").click(function() {
        window.location.href = this.src;
    });
});
```

For item #2, you may want to use delegated event handling instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "img", function() {
        window.location.href = this.src;
    });
});
```

For item #3, you need to check your browser error console or the debug console and see what script errors might be causing your scripts to stop executing prematurely.

---

P.S. You may also note that I've simplified your code a bit by just using `this.src` rather than `$(this).attr("src")`.  No point in using jQuery when it is just longer and slower.

Comment: Thanks for this! Adding a document ready seems to fix it, accepting this in 3 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Jquery is loaded before your script .Also if images are loaded dynamically use this script:

```
$('body').on('click','img', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    window.location.href=src;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your images absolute path names? if not, you want to do something like this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + src;
```

Comment: But op is not using `.prop()` he is using `.attr()`